# Python Files, Taking a file and finding averages

Tags: python, file, average

I'm trying to create a python program that can average the speed a car is going. However, their are different roads this speeds are found on (these are represented with numbers 0-9) the file could have any road number and could be any speed.

```
Example1.txt
0    40km
1    30km
0    67km
2    45km
2    23km
```

The program i want to create with take the average of the roads

```
average of 1 = 30
average of 0 = 35
```

so on, the file can contain however many pairings and the roads will be between numbers 0-9
This is what i have so far:

```
def traffic_summary(filename):
   in_file = open(filename)
   lines = in_file.readlines()
   in_file.close()
   return lines

def calc_traffic_avg(lines):
# Find out how long the file is
    total_lines = len(lines)  

# For every file line, find the charity and the amount contributed
    avg = 0     # Nums + however many / How ever many integers there are
    road_nums = []
    master = []
    road_speeds = []
    for i in range(1, total_lines):     # Omits the title lines
       current_line = lines[i].rstrip("\n")       #Removes the new line
       current_line = current_line.split()

       for j in range(len(current_line)):
          current_word = current_line[j]

          if "km" in current_word:
              position = j
              amount = int(current_word.rstrip('km'))
              road_speeds.append(amount)
          if not "km" in current_word:
              road_nums.append(int(current_word))
   print(road_nums, road_speeds)
```

I need to figure out how to average the number of speeds on the roads.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to know? To find the average you need to add up all the different speeds for a particular road and then divide that by the number of them that made up the sum.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is keep track of all speeds *for each road*, rather than just a list of all speeds and a list of all roads.

One way to do this is with a dictionary: the keys are the roads, and the values are a list or set* of speeds for that road. You can use `collections.defaultdict(list)` (or `…(set)`) to make this easy to build.

But also, you need to know which road each speed goes with. The way you've written things, you're just treating each word as a completely independent thing, ignoring the fact that they come in pairs (and other useful things, like the fact that there's always exactly one pair on each line), which means you have no way of knowing which goes with which.

If the file format really is as described, you can make this a lot simpler: instead of looping over `current_line`, use the fact that `current_line[0]` is the road and `current_line[1]` is the speed. Like this:

```
road_speeds = collections.defaultdict(list)

# ...

    # ... inside the loop

    road, speed = current_line.split()
    road = int(road)
    speed = int(speed.rstrip('km'))
    road_speeds[road].append(speed)
```

Now, when you finish the whole thing, you'll have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
{0: [40, 67], 2: [45, 23], 1: [30]}
```

So, how do you get the average speed for each road?

```
for road, speeds in road_speeds.items():
    average_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
    print(road, average_speed)
```

Note that if you have Python 3.4+, you may find it more readable or explicit to use `statistics.mean` instead of dividing the `sum` by the `len`.

---

<sub>* How do you know whether to use set or list? Basically, if it makes conceptual sense to treat duplicates differently, or to consider the order of the entries meaningful, then you have a list; otherwise, you have a set. In this case, if there are two trips with the same speed on the same road, you still probably want to consider them distinct trips, as [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) pointed out, so a list probably makes more sense here.</sub>

Comment: Is `set` really a good idea?  What if there are two trips at the same speed?

Answer (score 1):

[collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) will be useful:

```
from  collections import defaultdict,Counter
d =  defaultdict(float)
count = Counter() # get count of all times the  road appears in the file
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        rd, speed = line.rstrip().split()
        d[rd] += float(speed.rstrip("km")) # sum  km for each road/key 
        count.update(rd)

for k, v in d.items():
    print("Road {} average = {}".format(k,v/count[k])) # divide sum by times road appears

Road 1  average = 30.0
Road 0  average = 53.5
Road 2  average = 34.0
```

Comment: +1, need to skip first line , the program is failing otherwise

Comment: @RADAR, I did not see any header on the first line, all that is there is the name of the file?